# Swift: how to censor/filter text entered for swear words, etc?

Tags: ios, swift

I just want to see whether there is an established way to do this, or how one would go about this.

I have a text field that essentially acts as a form in my iOs app where a user can post something. I can't have users posting swear words/inappropriate crap, so I want to filter out and display an error if the string they enter contains one of these words.

How do other apps in Swift do this? Do they just search through the string to see if it contains the word (obviously not within other words, but standing alone) or is there another method?

How can I accurately filter out the swear words from my user post in Swift?

Comment: Make an array and check if field inputted text is in the array.

Comment: Or maybe there exists some kind of database of those words so you can use that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Construct a list of words you consider to be swear words, and simply check the user entered string whether any of these words are contained within the string.

**Swift 3:**

```
import Foundation

func containsSwearWord(text: String, swearWords: [String]) -> Bool {
    return swearWords
        .reduce(false) { $0 || text.contains($1.lowercased()) }
}

// example usage
let listOfSwearWords = ["darn", "crap", "newb"] 
    /* list as lower case */

let userEnteredText1 = "This darn didelo thread is a no no."
let userEnteredText2 = "This fine didelo thread is a go."

print(containsSwearWord(text: userEnteredText1, swearWords: listOfSwearWords)) // true
print(containsSwearWord(text: userEnteredText2, swearWords: listOfSwearWords)) // false
```

**Swift 2.2:**

```
import Foundation

func containsSwearWord(text: String, swearWords: [String]) -> Bool {
    return swearWords
        .reduce(false) { $0 || text.containsString($1.lowercaseString) }
}

// example usage
let listOfSwearWords = ["darn", "crap", "newb"]
/* list as lower case */

let userEnteredText1 = "This darn didelo thread is a no no."
let userEnteredText2 = "This fine didelo thread is a go."

print(containsSwearWord(userEnteredText1, swearWords: listOfSwearWords)) // true
print(containsSwearWord(userEnteredText2, swearWords: listOfSwearWords)) // false
```

Comment: IRL using `reduce` and `contains` for a long list of words (in all sorts of cases and so on, e.g. crap, cRAP, cRap, cR*p, etc.) would be inefficient because it works through the entire array and doesn't stop after the first instance is found. To do this while text is being typed definitely wouldn't work and even after a submit button is pressed it wouldn't be great.

Comment: You'd typically only call such an method above when the user attempts escape the keyboard, or, as you say, at submit. Also, Swift is fast, and using `.lowerCaseString` comparison (apply to `text` and keep list in lower case) is a natural choice rather including case variations. Finally, the Swift compiler is, even though young, quite clever, and since `||` is implemented lazily, I would _assume_ that using reduce as above allows short-circuiting. I'll need to test this theory later, though. Your regex options is probably a better choice, though, in case the list of bad words grow large.

Comment: Yes, you could lower case the string to solve part of the issue for a short post. I do stand by my issue with reduce though that you could be subject to too many unnecessary calls, and if you ordered swear words from most to least common then instances that return true would happen quickly. I'm not going to say that regex doesn't have its own performance issues because I'm sure others will point to them but in-built approaches might be better optimised to search.

Comment: @sketchyTech I just tested (make sure to test in an actual project and not a playground) and `reduce` as above is evaluated allowing short-circuiting; i.e., after first hit (`true`) it terminates. My guess is the compiler reduces (no pun intended) the above `reduce` to something similar to the manual `for` loop you suggested for the edit (thanks for the edit suggestion! But I will keep the `reduce` solution given the results as described by this comment).

Comment: (... also note that as mentioned above, Swift is quite quick: for a list of `10 000` bad words, for a given text of `~500` characters, the worst case scenario (search full list without a single hit/early exit) executes at `~0.1s` on an iPhone 6. The pure `for` loop approach is quicker given early escapes (for some reason: `reduce` _does_ short-circuit, but seemingly not really as quick), but worst-case scenario of no hits is the same for a classic `for` loop and for `reduce`. Anyway, that is a very large sized list, and _if_  we reach those sizes I guess a regex approach is more sensible).

Comment: that is interesting about the short-circuiting, thanks for taking the time to perform these tests

Answer (score 4):

I created a class that enables you to feed a string in and remove profanity. [Here's a link to the repo](https://github.com/AdrianBinDC/ProfanityFilter).

Here's the code:

```
class ProfanityFilter: NSObject {

    static let sharedInstance = ProfanityFilter()
    private override init() {}

    // Customize as needed
    private let dirtyWords = "\\b(ducker|mother ducker|motherducker|shot|bad word|another bad word|)\\b"

    // Courtesy of Martin R
    // https://stackoverflow.com/users/1187415/martin-r
    private func matches(for regex: String, in text: String) -> [String] {

        do {
            let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: regex, options: [.caseInsensitive])
            let nsString = text as NSString
            let results = regex.matches(in: text, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: nsString.length))
            return results.map { nsString.substring(with: $0.range)}
        } catch let error {
            print("invalid regex: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return []
        }
    }

    public func cleanUp(_ string: String) -> String {
        let dirtyWords = matches(for: self.dirtyWords, in: string)

        if dirtyWords.count == 0 {
            return string
        } else {
            var newString = string

            dirtyWords.forEach({ dirtyWord in
                let newWord = String(repeating: "", count: dirtyWord.characters.count)
                newString = newString.replacingOccurrences(of: dirtyWord, with: newWord, options: [.caseInsensitive])
            })

            return newString
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
 yourLabel.text = ProfanityFilter.sharedInstance.cleanUp(yourString)
```

Answer (score 3):

Extension checking for foul language.

**Swift 4.2**

Example Usage:

```
"poop".containsBadWord()
```

Extension:

```
extension String {

    func containsBadWord()->Bool {
        //Sorry for bad words
        let badWords = ["insert","bad","words","here","poop"]
        for word in badWords {
            if lowercased().contains(word) {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }

}
```

Comment: Dont know why but this feels inefficient… or am I wrong here …?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking into an `API` to which you can submit a string and get a `JSON` response containing information such as:

- Is the string bad?
- Total # of bad words contained in string
- An array containing all recognized bad words
- A censored version of the input string

I found a couple sources via Google. Check these out and do a little more research to find if an `API` is the best fit for you and which one you should use. **I would assume that using an `API` like the one I have listed below would be the most practical approach**, as you would **NOT** have to compile a list of "bad" words yourself and use resources from the device to sort through the list (which can contain thousands of words).

Rather, you can **simply submit a string using the `API` to get a network response containing the data in JSON format** from the `API` server.

Why not let the API Server do the logic for you and just spit out an answer?

---

[NeutrinoAPI](https://www.neutrinoapi.com/api/bad-word-filter/)

Answer (score 1):

If this method returns a range,

```
str.range(of: "darn|crap|newb", options: [.regularExpressionSearch, .caseInsensitiveSearch], range: str.startIndex..<str.endIndex, locale:nil)
```

an offensive word has been found. While this method can be used to remove the offending strings:

```
str.replacingOccurrences(of: "darn|crap|newb", with: "", options: [.regularExpressionSearch, .caseInsensitiveSearch])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you filter bad words locally you wouldn’t easily accommodate many languages, also as new bad words appear, you would have to waste a developers time manually putting in bad words, alternatively, there are apis designed for this purpose: https://www.moderatecontent.com/documentation/badwords