# How can I stop users from writing curse words in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, firebase, filter, swift3, textview

I'm Using **Swift 3** and **firebase** to create a social app where users can make posts but the thing is that I don't want the users to use **curse words**.

Is there a way like to **replace** these words when the users writes them?
Currently the users use a **text view** to write the things they want to post...

How can I do it in like the easiest and simple way?

I was looking for answers and I find this question [Swift: how to censor/filter text entered for swear words, etc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38185917/swift-how-to-censor-filter-text-entered-for-swear-words-etc).
With this answer code:

```
import Foundation

func containsSwearWord(text: String, swearWords: [String]) -> Bool {
return swearWords
    .reduce(false) { $0 || text.contains($1.lowercased()) }
}

// example usage
let listOfSwearWords = ["darn", "crap", "newb"] 
    /* list as lower case */

let userEnteredText1 = "This darn didelo thread is a no no."
let userEnteredText2 = "This fine didelo thread is a go."

print(containsSwearWord(text: userEnteredText1, swearWords: listOfSwearWords)) // true
print(containsSwearWord(text: userEnteredText2, swearWords: listOfSwearWords)) // false
```

But I don't really get it. How can I implement that in my project? Where should I paste that code? Or how can I link that code to my **text view**? And what it´s missing on that code to work as it should be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use UITextField on .editingChanged event.

```
 inputTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)

 func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
        print(containsSwearWord(text: textField, swearWords: listOfSwearWords)) // Here you check every text change on input UITextField
}
```

**UPDATE**

You must implement **UITextViewDelegate** ([Official Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextviewdelegate))

**Validate before input ends**

In `textViewShouldEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView)` validate user input and return true/false to allow editing end.

**Validate after input ends**

In `textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView)` validate user input and show any warning if you found not allowed words.

Comment: But what happens if I'm using a UITextView? I still don't get it! 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it.

- Pass TextView text to NSString
- Convert NSString to NSArray
- Check to see if that NSArray contains one of your curse string. If it does then do replace it with **** or something.

This is how it would look in objective-C.

```
NSString *textViewStr = myTextView.text;
NSArray *myArray1 = [textViewStr componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]; //this will put all words separated by space into an array
if ( [myArray1 containsObject:@"crap"] ) {
    //found one
    textViewStr = [textViewStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"crap"
                                     withString:@"duck"];
}
```

while googling I found another better answer.

```
//If you want multiple string replacement:
NSString *s = @"foo/bar:baz.foo";
NSCharacterSet *doNotWant = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"/:."];
s = [[s componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: doNotWant] componentsJoinedByString: @""];
NSLog(@"%@", s); // => foobarbazfoo
```

[String replacement in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668228/string-replacement-in-objective-c)